# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, webpack

I'm trying to migrate my build from gulp to Webpack 2. Some background: this is a client + server project, so there is a tiny express server which serves up the client files and also serves as a backend for REST calls. In the Webpack version the express server will also run the webpack middleware (in development only).

Now, when I'm starting the server (and webpack middleware) up, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/development/layrz/annotations/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib'
 @ ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 16:9-22
 @ ./~/d3-request/build/d3-request.node.js
 @ ./client/scripts/utils/Utils.js
 @ ./client/scripts/components/account/accountPage.js
 @ ./client/scripts/app.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client/scripts/app.js
```

I tried targeting Node, but then I run into problems around require not being found.

Also, providing the 'node' config object didn't solve the issue.

The real question may be why importing 'd3-request' resolves to 'd3-request.node.js'

Comment: well, client side can't access `fs` because that's browser code, right?

Comment: Sure :) but why importing 'd3-request' ends up importing d3-request.node.js is really the question here I think

Comment: true, not that you stated that in the question :p

Comment: Agreed :) it's an evolving question lol

Comment: You could try setting `resolve.mainFields: ['browser', 'main']`. Worth a go.

Comment: Tried it just now, same results unfortunately. I'm considering removing d3 and using fetch, but thought I'd try to understand this first. Not sure what makes Webpack pick the file with the 'node' qualifier in it, rather than just picking the normal file.